# Unable to retrieve JaCoCo coverage from exec file via Java API

Tags: java, api, jacoco

We have JaCoCo for coverage. Some tests spawn a new java process for which I add the jacocoagent arguments and I get the expected jacoco.exec. Each file has a different path.

i.e. `-javaagent:path/jacoco.jar=destfile=path/to/output.exec`

I merge those and generate a report in which they correctly show as covered from those external processes.

Later I try to use the merged.exec using the Java API but I can't get coverage on those methods to perform some internal calculations.

In some cases I found that there might be multiple class coverage records for certain line (I assume depending on how many times that particular line was executed) so I use the following methods to get the best coverage out of those:

```
private List<IClassCoverage> getJacocoCoverageData(ExecutionDataStore 
execDataStore,
          String classFile) throws IOException
  {
    List<IClassCoverage> result = new ArrayList<>();
    logger.debug("Processing coverage for class: " + classFile);
    final CoverageBuilder coverageBuilder = new CoverageBuilder();
    final Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer(execDataStore, coverageBuilder);
    File file = new File(this.workspaceRoot, classFile);
    logger.debug("Analyzing coverage in: " + file);
    if (file.exists())
    {
      try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file))
      {
        analyzer.analyzeClass(fis, file.getAbsolutePath());
      }
      Iterator<IClassCoverage> it = coverageBuilder.getClasses().iterator();
      while (it.hasNext())
      {
        result.add(it.next());
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  private IClassCoverage getBestCoverage(List<IClassCoverage> coverage,
          int workingCopyLine)
  {
    IClassCoverage coverageData = null;
    for (IClassCoverage cc : coverage)
    {
      ILine temp = cc.getLine(workingCopyLine);
      if (coverageData == null
              || temp.getStatus()
              > coverageData.getLine(workingCopyLine).getStatus())
      {
        coverageData = cc;
      }
    }
    return coverageData;
  }
```

Somehow I only find not covered coverage data. Both the reports and the methods above look at the same merged.exec file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be something completely unrelated to the JaCoCo file. The code above worked fine.